# updating an old version of my app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to update an old version of my app, in the store, it doesn't show iOS on VERSION OR PLATFORM it only shows the tvOS, how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. In my case I wanted to update the app to a newer version which wasn't listed in the "+Version or Platform" menu. The possible reason is that a previous build failed, with the status of "Prepare for Submission".

I deleted the build file related to that failed build and uploaded the new correct one. After that I changed the failed build version to the same version of my new build (This can be done under iTunes connect -> IOS App -> Scroll down to Version)

After doing that I was able to submit it to the App Store.